# I'm attempting to reset the timer when the absolute value of x-a and x-b is greater than 150.

Tags: c#, timer

This code is used to evaluate the information given by a timer.  I want it to activate when the timing is valid and I want the timer to reset when certain criteria occurs.  And I want the code to continually check these parameters.  x, a, and b continually change.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); //sets sw as the stopwatch variable
sw.Start(); //starts stopwatch
for (int i = 0; ; i++) //counter
{
     if (i % 1000000 == 0) //sets counter limit
     {
          sw.Stop();  //stops stopwatch
          if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 3000)  //when the elapsed time is > 3 secs
          {
              comPort.WriteLine("1"); //sends a 1 to an arduino 
              break; //breaks for loop
          }
          else if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 3000) //when the elapsed time is < 3 secs
          {
              if ((Math.Abs(x-a) < 150) && (Math.Abs(x-b) < 150)) //criteria to start
              {
                  sw.Start(); //continues stopwatch
              }
              else if ((Math.Abs(x-a) > 150) && (Math.Abs(x-b) > 150)) //criteria reset
              {
                  sw.Reset(); //resets stopwatch
                  break; //breaks for loop
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you think StackOverFlow Q&A exchange site is a homework helper site ?

Comment: @DavutGürbüz No, but its for help with programming in general. A good explanation by a peer as to what is wrong with the code can be much more helpful than an explanation by a professor.

Comment: @TheGreatCO You can be sure I didn't give to jeff a -1. But any SO user doesn't welcome with these things; Please help! It is urgent ! As soon as possible ! especially homework. You do not need these expressions. Just take effort & research and ask what you can't find out.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious problem that I see--the stopwatch is stopped for basically the whole loop.  It's not going to do anything resembling keeping proper time.

Comment: I'm confused on why you say that.  It should restart each time x-a and x-b are greater than 150.  From testing, the code sends the "1" to the arduino when x-a and x-b are less than 150 for 3 secs, but the restarting doesn't occur for the other condition.  If proper timing doesn't occur, then can you help to explain why the "1" is being sent to the arduino to activate our system?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A big flag I see here is that you're polling the stopwatch by iterating a for loop.  This uses unnecessary CPU resources.  It'd be better to switch to an event driven system, using `System.Timers.Timer` objects, and enabling them as logic dictates.  Below is an implementation of your logic in the example above using Timers instead.  One timer is set to check the value of **x** every 500 milliseconds, and turns on the 3 second timer accordingly.

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class HelloWorld
{
    static int a = 0, x = 0, b = 100;
    static Timer timerOut, timerCheck;

    static public void Main()
    {
        timerOut = new Timer(3000);
        timerOut.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnOutElapsed);
        timerCheck = new Timer(500); 
        timerCheck.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnCheckElapsed);
        timerCheck.Start();

        for(;;) {
            Console.WriteLine("Input x or (Q)uit");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            if(s.ToLower() == "q") break;
            x = Convert.ToInt32(s);
        }
    }

    private static void OnCheckElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if((Math.Abs(x-a) < 150) && (Math.Abs(x-b) < 150)) {
            if(!timerOut.Enabled) {
                Console.WriteLine("starting timer (x={0})",x);
                timerOut.Start(); 
            }
        }
        else if((Math.Abs(x-a) > 150) && (Math.Abs(x-b) > 150)) {
            if(timerOut.Enabled) {
                Console.WriteLine("stopping timer (x={0})",x);
                timerOut.Stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnOutElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("write to com port");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to c# coding.  I'm a little confused about what the for loop is doing under the Main() method, as well as, what the purpose of the Console.WriteLine is?

Comment: The above example is meant to be run as a console application.  The loop is just so you can change the value of x when running the example above from a console window.  `Console.WriteLine` writes a string to the console to be displayed to the user.  You can think of that for-loop as the rest of your application changing the values of `x`, `a`, and `b`.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be resetting the timer once it has been enabled.  I'm using the Microsoft Kinect data, and in my code, x is the shoulderCenter depth, a is the Handleft depth, and b is the Handright depth.  Those positions are constantly updating; however, once the OnOutElapsed function is run, it doesn't seem to ever turn off.

Comment: after initializing `timerOut`, add the line `timerOut.AutoReset = False;` to make the **Timer** only fire once.

Comment: do you think if i have the xbox kinect facing the ground instead of sitting on a table, that it will mess up the ability for it to track a user?